# How to write an async redux test with firebase login?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-redux, firebase-authentication, jestjs

I have no idea how to write a test for this type of problem

`auth.js`

```
export const onLogin = ({email, password}) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const user = await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    dispatch(loginSuccess(user))
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error)
    dispatch(loginError(error))
  }
}
```

and what I have so far in my `auth.test.js`

```js
it(`creates ${LOGIN_SUCCESS} when login is successful`, () => {
  const expectedAction = {
    type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
    payload: { user: { email: 'test@test.com', emailVerified: true, displayName: 'test' } }
  };
  const store = mockStore({ type: null, payload: null });

  const form = { email: 'test@test.com', password: 'test' };

  return store.dispatch(actions.onLogin(form)).then(() => {
    expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedAction);
  });
});
```

Can anyone help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution:

`auth.ts`:

```
import firebase from './firebase';

export const LOGIN_SUCCESS = 'LOGIN_SUCCESS';
export const LOGIN_ERROR = 'LOGIN_ERROR';

export const loginSuccess = user => ({ type: LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload: { user } });
export const loginError = error => ({ type: LOGIN_ERROR, payload: error, error: true });

export const onLogin = ({ email, password }) => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const user = await firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);
    dispatch(loginSuccess(user));
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    dispatch(loginError(error));
  }
};
```

In order to keep it simple, I simulate the `firebase` module. You can use the real one.

`firebase.ts`:

```
const firebase = {
  auth() {
    return firebase;
  },
  async signInWithEmailAndPassword(email: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
    return firebase;
  }
};

export default firebase;
```

`auth.test.ts`:

```
import { LOGIN_SUCCESS, LOGIN_ERROR } from './auth';
import * as actions from './auth';
import createMockStore from 'redux-mock-store';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import firebase from './firebase';

jest.mock('./firebase.ts', () => {
  return {
    auth: jest.fn().mockReturnThis(),
    signInWithEmailAndPassword: jest.fn().mockReturnThis()
  };
});

const initialState = {};
const middlewares = [thunk];
const mockStore = createMockStore(middlewares);

describe('auth', () => {
  const form = { email: 'test@test.com', password: 'test' };
  let store;
  beforeEach(() => {
    store = mockStore(initialState);
  });

  describe('#onLogin', () => {
    it('should login success', () => {
      expect.assertions(2);
      const mockedUser = { email: 'test@test.com', emailVerified: true, displayName: 'test' };
      (firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword as jest.MockedFunction<
        typeof firebase.signInWithEmailAndPassword
      >).mockResolvedValueOnce(mockedUser);

      const expectedAction = [
        {
          type: LOGIN_SUCCESS,
          payload: { user: mockedUser }
        }
      ];

      return store.dispatch(actions.onLogin(form)).then(() => {
        expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedAction);
        expect(firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword).toBeCalledWith(form.email, form.password);
      });
    });

    it('should login error', () => {
      expect.assertions(2);
      const mockedError = new Error('firebase error');
      (firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword as jest.MockedFunction<
        typeof firebase.signInWithEmailAndPassword
      >).mockRejectedValueOnce(mockedError);

      const expectedAction = [
        {
          type: LOGIN_ERROR,
          payload: mockedError,
          error: true
        }
      ];

      return store.dispatch(actions.onLogin(form)).then(() => {
        expect(store.getActions()).toEqual(expectedAction);
        expect(firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword).toBeCalledWith(form.email, form.password);
      });
    });
  });
});
```

Unit test result with 100% coverage:

```sh
 PASS  src/stackoverflow/52550469/auth.test.ts
  auth
    #onLogin
      ✓ should login success (6ms)
      ✓ should login error (7ms)

  console.error src/stackoverflow/52550469/auth.ts:3341
    Error: firebase error
        at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/src/stackoverflow/52550469/auth.test.ts:48:27)
        at Object.asyncJestTest (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/jasmineAsyncInstall.js:102:37)
        at resolve (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:43:12)
        at new Promise (<anonymous>)
        at mapper (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:26:19)
        at promise.then (/Users/ldu020/workspace/github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/node_modules/jest-jasmine2/build/queueRunner.js:73:41)
        at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)

----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
File      |  % Stmts | % Branch |  % Funcs |  % Lines | Uncovered Line #s |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
All files |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
 auth.ts  |      100 |      100 |      100 |      100 |                   |
----------|----------|----------|----------|----------|-------------------|
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       2 passed, 2 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        3.086s, estimated 4s
```

Here is the completed demo: https://github.com/mrdulin/jest-codelab/tree/master/src/stackoverflow/52550469